# font-face Styled components - OTS parsing error: invalid version tag

Tags: javascript, webpack, styled-components

I'm trying to add several local fonts to a new website. The fonts seem to be downloaded correctly and the font-face is defined as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('/fonts/roboto-mono-v5-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Roboto Mono'), local('RobotoMono-Regular'),
     url('/fonts/roboto-mono-v5-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
     url('/fonts/roboto-mono-v5-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
     url('/fonts/roboto-mono-v5-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
     url('/fonts/roboto-mono-v5-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
     url('/fonts/roboto-mono-v5-latin-regular.svg#RobotoMono') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

But still I get the following error:

[image]

**You can chek my webpack configuration** [**here**](https://github.com/webmadeira/webmadeira.github.io/blob/feature/font-faces/webpack.common.js).

#### This is a public repo and the problem can be reproduced when running the project in local:

1. Clone: `git clone -b feature/font-faces https://github.com/webmadeira/webmadeira.github.io.git`
2. Install dependencies: `npm install`
3. Run project: `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change my webpack config from:

```
{
  test: /.(png|jpg|jp(e)?g|svg)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      publicPath: 'images',
      name: '/[name].[ext]',
    },
  },
},
```

To:

```
{
  test: /.(png|jpg|jp(e)?g|svg)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
    },
  },
},
```